# Bound combo box in form does not always update table

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox

I'm struggling with a problem which I can't work out is due to a logical error, a design error or both. Or maybe it's something else entirely.

I have created a simple customer services database and form based user-interface for my company. When a user answers the phone they are supposed to log the call in the system if it is an issue relating to a product.
Sometimes a chain of stores which we have a special relationship with calls up on behalf of customers and we take their reference number and give them ours. This system actually works pretty well if I may say so myself (!), but I noticed after a while that when this store calls up and gives us their number, when they are logged into the system their branch number/name is not updated in the table record.

Here is a summarised outline of the relevant database tables. I renamed the store to SpecialStore:

- Issues

  - IssueReference
  - ProductID
  - CustomerID
  - SpecialStoreBranch
- Customers

  - ...
- Products

  - ...
- SpecialStore

  - SS_ID
  - City
  - Address

The idea is that even if it is either a customer or the store with their own IDs, the products are still stored in the same `Products` table, just with either the `CustomerID` or `SS_ID` filled in. Then when issues are logged, the store or customer is set and logged against a product.

In my main form I have a variety of boxes for a new issue to be filled in. There are combo boxes to select the `CustomerID`, `ProductID` etc, and of course the `SpecialStoreBranch`. These are all bound to the table, and the combo boxes all have row sources relating to their particular table. E.g. `CustomerID` combo box is a list of the IDs in the `Customers` table. (This is filtered to the required one elsewhere in the form.)

The Issues table `SpecialStoreBranch` field has the following query as its `Row Source`:

```
SELECT SpecialStore.[SS_ID], [SpecialStore].[City] FROM SpecialStore;
```

This is the same row source for the combo box on my main form.
The `Column Count` is 2, with the `Bound Column` as `0` and the column widths, if necessary, are `1cm;2.544cm`.

My main form combo box `SpecialStoreBranch` has the other attributes:

```
Limit to List = yes
Allow Value List Edits = no
Inherit Value List = yes
Show Only Row Source Values = no
```

On the form the `CustomerID` and `ProductID` store correctly when the record is saved, and they are also from combo boxes. The form refreshes to update those fields when another part of the form (adding new customers and products) is changed. Could this be why the `SpecialStoreBranch` does not update? What am I missing? Is there a way to test this? I have been trying to run user tests to see if it ever works, but all I know is that it doesn't always set. If I have forgotten a piece of information let me know.

Edit:
Looking here: [BoundColumn-Propery](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/BoundColumn-Property-2524fb4c-20ef-4b4e-a5ed-f1e5952ec459), I'm not sure if setting the bound column to 0 is doing what I think it's doing. But even then it should still use that id number to input into the table I would have thought and if they are all the same, what does it matter. When I tried setting it to 1, it took the text value in the table. Confusing!

Comment: The BoundColumn property should be set to 1 to save the value from the first column of the RowSource. Is SS_ID a text data type?

Comment: Take programming documentation very literally. You say "even then it should still use that id number..."  WRONG. When `BoundColumn = 0` it uses the LIST INDEX value. Only coincidentally will your data _id number_ match the list index. It probably works sometimes only by chance when [id number] = list index. The list index will always go from 0 to N-1 in order as the items appear in the dropdown list. But your data can really be in any order and might not even be numeric. I supposed BoundColumn = 0 might be useful in some case, but don't use it unless you know exactly why you are using it.

Comment: @CPerkins thanks. Yeh, sometimes I have to check myself that I'm not making assumptions, but I didn't appreciate until I looked it up that the `0` value for `BoundColumn` was the list index. Having said that, I should have known as in computing lists are often indexed starting with 0. Somewhere along the way I confused it with the ID field values, which whilst unique is definitely not a list index.